# Unable to get Date in required SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Below is the my code for Simple date format.Where iam getting o/p as

1. `2012-03-13`
2. `13:15:00-4:00`
3. `2012/03/13 13:15:00 +0530`

but i need the o/p in the format     `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`

```
public class Time {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            SimpleDateFormat ti=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z");
            String dt=    "2012-03-13T13:15:00-4:00";

        String st[]=dt.split("T");
        System.out.println(st[0]);
        System.out.println(st[1]);

        String time[]= st[1].split("-");

        Date fromDt =(Date)sdf.parse(st[0]+" "+time[0]);



        System.out.println(sdf1.format(fromDt));


    }

}
```

Comment: Is -0400 is your [Z timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone)? Or it is -4:00 amount of time in m(m):ss format you want to substract from given date?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Not sure I understand properly, but it seems your last line should be:</s>

```
System.out.println(ti.format(fromDt)); //prints 03/13/2012 13:15
```

If your input were properly formatted (note the `-04:00` instead of `-4:00` in dt), you could just do this:

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
String dt = "2012-03-13T13:15:00-04:00";
Date date = input.parse(dt);
System.out.println(output.format(date)); //prints 03/13/2012 17:15 with my local timezone
output.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-08:00"));
System.out.println(output.format(date)); //prints 03/13/2012 09:15
```

Note: `XXX` has been introduced in Java 7 so would not work with an earlier version of the JDK.

Comment: ya if i do in such way then i will get but there will be missing -4:00 which is provided in input. please check the i/p (string dt)once

Comment: What do you expect the last line to print? `03/13/2012 17:15`?

Comment: See my edit - you need to insert a `0` before `4:00` to parse it with `XXX` - that should not be too complicated.

Comment: thanks for the reply but iam getting 22:45 when  I used same code as u said , but iam expecting 9:15

Comment: @assylias What version of java introduces the X character in SimpleDateFormat? I get "Illegal pattern character 'X'" when I try to use it

Comment: @Adam http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html - It seems it has been introduced in Java 7...

Comment: @assylias Spec in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html states X is an ISO8601 timezone which must have hours expressed as TwoDigitHours, i.e. -04:00 not -4.00. Surprised its parsing it OK...

Comment: @Adam Indeed, in my answer, I have added the leading `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a 'T' literal in your format, then SimpleDateFormat will do the parsing for you. Here's a solution that works in java 6, and deals with -4.00, it works by separating out the junk at the end of the line and asking TimeZone to convert it, that timeZone is then used on the SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");

String dt = "2012-03-13T13:15:00 -4:00";

Pattern pattern = Pattern
        .compile("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s*(.*)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(dt);
if (m.find()) {
    String zoneJunk = m.group(1);
    TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + zoneJunk);
    input.setTimeZone(zone);
}

Date date = input.parse(dt);
System.out.println(output.format(date)); // prints 03/13/2012 17:15
```

Comment: here i need time zone iam expecting o/p as  03/13/2012 9:15

Comment: @yyyi777 Updated to deal with time zone.